# Using the Cauchy Condensation Test to determine convergence/divergence of a series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider the two series

$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^p(\ln n)^q}$ for any $p,q$

and

$\sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac{1}{n^p(\ln n)^q (\ln \ln n)^r }$ for any $p,q,r$.

How can one determine the conditions for convergence and divergence?

Answer (score 0):

the first series is convergent for:

1)  $p>1, q \in (-\infty,\infty)$

2) $p=1, q>1$

the first series is divergent for:

1) $p<1,  q \in (-\infty,\infty)$

2) $p=1, q\le 1$

the second  series is convergent for:

1)  $p>1, q, r \in (-\infty,\infty)$

2) $p=1, q>1, r \in (-\infty,\infty)$

3) $p=1, q=1, r >1$

the second series is divergent for:

1) $p<1,  q, r \in (-\infty,\infty)$

2) $p=1, q < 1, r \in (-\infty,\infty)$ $

3)  $p=1, q = 1, r \le 1 $

Comment: how did you find these relationships?

Comment: How does the Cauchy Condensation Test lead to those results?  The question explicitly asks for that test to be used.