# Discuss the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}(\log n)^{\beta}(\log\log n)^{\gamma}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I have tried with the Maclaurin-Cauchy test in two different cases:

- $\alpha=1$, $\beta=1$ and $\gamma=0$:
  $$\int_{1}^{n}\frac{1}{x\log x}dx=\infty,$$
  so the series is divergent.
- $\alpha=1,\beta\neq1$ and $\gamma=0$:
  $$\int_{1}^{n}\frac{1}{x(\log x)^{\beta}}dx=\frac{(\log n)^{1-\beta}}{1-\beta},$$
  so if $\beta>1$ the series is convergent and if $\beta<1$ the series is divergent.
- $\alpha=1, \beta=1$ and $\gamma\neq1$:
  $$\int_{1}^{n}\frac{1}{x\log x (\log\log x)^{\gamma}}dx=\frac{1}{1-\gamma}((\log\log n)^{1-\gamma}-\infty^{1-\gamma}),$$
  so if $\gamma>1$ the series is convergent and if $\gamma<1$ the series is divergent.

I have also tried the case $\alpha=1, \beta=1$ and $\gamma=1$, but that just gives me an integral which is not possible to evaluate (you get something like $\log(-\infty)$), that is obviously not defined.

I don't know if my tests are correct or if I have forgotten to consider any case.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This has been asked and answered several times: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1700123/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2230660/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1215381/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1825008/42969

Comment: The reasoning for the case $\alpha=\beta=1$ is flawed. You have taken the lower limit so low that that $\log\log x$ is not even defined for small $x$. Its not the case that you get "$\infty^{1-\gamma}$" that is the cause of the divergence but rather that $(\log\log n)^{1-\gamma}$ diverges when $n$ grows.

Comment: Remember what the integral test says: convergence/divergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)$ is linked to the convergence/divergence of $\int_{x_0}^\infty f(x) dx$ no matter what $x_0$ is. So you should pick $x_0$ large enough such that all it well defined.

Comment: Oh, OK. I didn't know that. I thought the integral had to be always evaluated from x=1.

Comment: ...and btw if $\gamma=1$ then you get $\int \frac{dx}{x\log(x)\log\log(x)} = \log\log\log(x) + C$ so this case can also be solved.

Comment: If we take $x_{0}=2$, for example, we obtain $\log\log\log n - \log\log\log 2$, which tends to $\infty$ when $n$ tends to $\infty$, so the series in that case would be divergent. Am I right?

Comment: Almost. $\log\log 2 < 0$ so $\log\log\log(2)$ is not defined. Thus $2$ is too small and $e=2.71\ldots$ is the smallest number possible for the integral to be well defined (pick $x_0=e^e$ and the last term is zero).

Comment: Ok, you're right. Thanks!